# Occurrences of D. H. Lehmer's 10-th degree polynomial

Tags: big-list, examples

Salem numbers and Lehmer's minimum height problem are venerated not only in number theory and diophantine analysis, where they are considered naturally interesting for their own sake, but also in fields such as hyperbolic geometry and holomorphic dynamics. As is so well known, the least known Salem number is a root $1.176280\ldots$ of the following monic reciprocal $10$-th degree $\{-1,0,1\}-$polynomial discovered way back in 1933 by D. H. Lehmer in his work on primality testing:
$$
x^{10} + x^9 - x^7 - x^6 - x^5 - x^4 - x^3 + x + 1.
$$

I am interested in seeing any mathematical contexts or computations through which this particular polynomial shows up, apparently accidental occurrences included (not to say preferred).

Here is an example from topology: this is the Alexander polynomial of infinitely many knots, including the $(-2,3,7)$-pretzel knot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a paper of McMullen where the Lehmer polynomial shows up (see Theorem 1.2 there):

http://www.math.harvard.edu/~ctm/papers/home/text/papers/blowup/blowup.pdf

Comment: Here are the slides for a talk of McMullen's http://www.math.harvard.edu/~ctm/expositions/home/text/talks/princeton/2011_adler/slides.pdf which cover that example and many others.

Comment: Also this is an example in dynamics, and so maybe is not quite what you were looking for.  In any case, this is an excellent question, and I look forward to the answers.

Comment: It is a beautiful article. In this connexion there are two additional papers by McMullen: "Coxeter groups, Salem numbers and the Hilbert metric," and "Cyclotomic factors of Coxeter polynomials." (The latter is joint with B. Gross and Eriko Hironaka.) Luckily, also available is the full video of McMullen's 1 hour lecture: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lbd4WEckLWs .

Answer (score 5):

well, this link will direct you to just under 300 scholarly articles on Lehmer's polynomial:

http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=polynomial+lehmer&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0%2C5&cites=18047953845360790641&scipsc=1

(oh, and I added the big-list tag to this question, I guess that is appropriate :)

---

a small selection:

- [The
  Lehmer polynomial and pretzel links](http://www.math.fsu.edu/~hironaka/papers/pretzel.pdf)
- [What is Lehmer's Number?](http://www.math.fsu.edu/~hironaka/papers/Whatis.pdf)
- [Heights of polynomials and entropy in algebraic dynamics](http://dro.dur.ac.uk/10056/1/10056.pdf)
- [On the
  distribution of the roots of a polynomial with integral
  coefficients](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.2307/2031711)
- [Primes in sequences associated to polynomials (after Lehmer)](https://ueaeprints.uea.ac.uk/19687/1/lms2000-004.pdf)
- [Lehmer's
  problem for compact Abelian groups](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2005-133-05/S0002-9939-04-07753-6/)
- [Higher
  Mahler measure for cyclotomic polynomials and Lehmer's question](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11139-010-9278-6#page-1)
- [Lehmer's Conjecture for
  Hermitian Matrices over the Eisenstein and Gaussian Integers](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.1734)
- [Solved
  and unsolved problems on polynomials](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/bcp/bcp34/bcp34112.pdf)
- [Polynomials with restricted coefficients and prescribed noncyclotomic factors](http://journals.cambridge.org/production/action/cjoGetFulltext?fulltextid=6560800)
- [A seventeenth-order polylogarithm ladder](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math.CA/9906134)
- [Lehmer's question, knots and surface dynamics](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math.GT/0509068)

Comment: Thank you for this search. The first paper, by Eriko Hironaka, is particular interesting. We learn from her article that the first historical appearance of that polynomial actually appears to be in Reidemeister's book on knot theory, which was published in 1932 and preceded Lehmer's paper by several months. A remarkable coincidence.